# Evaluate the following integral by using beta and gamma functions $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{m-1}+x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{m+n}.}$ How to evaluate this

Tags: calculus, special-functions

Evaluate the following integral by using beta and gamma functions $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{m-1}+x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{m+n}.}$

How to evaluate this?

I took $\frac{2x}{1+x}=y$ and trying to convert into beta function, but I could not get the answer.

Comment: I took 2x/1+x=y and trying to convert into beta function, but I could not get.

Comment: Yes sir I know the definition

Comment: Usually, this integral is given with the upper integration limit $\infty$, not $1$. Are you sure it is $1$? With the current integration bounds, WolframAlpha finds [a result involving hypergeometric functions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Bx%5Ea+%2F+(1%2Bx)%5Eb,%7Bx,0,1%7D%5D), so if I were you I would check the original statement of the problem again.

Comment: Integral limit is right sir.I write $I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{m-1}}{(1+x)^{m+n}}+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{m+n}}=I_1+I_2.$

Comment: With $\int_0^\infty$ I get beta function, but with $\int_0^1$ I only get hypergeometric.

Comment: Integral limit is right sir.I write                                   $I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{m-1}}{(1+x)^{m+n}}+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{m+n}}=I_1+I_2.$                                                                                            put $x=1/z $in $I_2$ we have $I_2=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n-1}}{(1+z)^{m+n}}$ Now I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{m-1}}{(1+x)^{m+n}}+\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{m-1}}{(1+z)^{m+n}}                                        =\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{m-1}}{(1+x)^{m+n}}=\beta(m,n)$ This s wht I have done. Is this right?

Comment: I can't also make it into the beta function. That upper limit really bothers.

Comment: They are incomplete Beta functions.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\limits_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{m}+x^{n}}{(1+x)^{m+n}} \mathrm{d}x = \mathrm{B}(m,n)$$

Proof:
We begin with the basic integral definition of the beta function

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{B}(x,y) = \int\limits^{1}_{0} t^{x-1} (1-t)^{y-1} \mathrm{d} t
\label{eq:bf1}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
for $\Re x \gt 0$ and $\Re y \gt 0$.

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{B}(x,y) = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{v^{x-1}}{(1+v)^{x+y}} \mathrm{d} v
\label{eq:bf2}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}

To derive this equation, we begin with \eqref{eq:bf1} and make the substitution

\begin{equation}
t = \frac{v}{1+v}
\end{equation}

to obtain

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{B}(x,y) = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{v^{x-1}}{(1+v)^{x-1}} \Big(1 - \frac{v}{1+v}\Big)^{y-1} \frac{1}{(1+v)^{2}} \mathrm{d} v
\end{equation}

simplification yields \eqref{eq:bf2}.

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{B}(x,y) = \int\limits_{0}^{1} \frac{(v^{x-1}+v^{y-1})}{(1+v)^{x+y}} \mathrm{d} v
\label{eq:bf3}
\tag{3}
\end{equation}

To obtain \eqref{eq:bf3} we begin with \eqref{eq:bf2} and break up the integral

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{B}(x,y) = \int\limits_{0}^{1} \frac{v^{x-1}}{(1+v)^{x+y}} \mathrm{d} v + \int\limits_{1}^{\infty} \frac{v^{x-1}}{(1+v)^{x+y}} \mathrm{d} v
\end{equation}

and designate the last integral as I.

For I, we make the substitution $w = v^{-1}$

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{I} = \int\limits_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{w^{x-1}} \frac{w^{x+y}}{(1+w)^{x+y}} \frac{1}{w^{2}} \mathrm{d} w
\end{equation}

Simplifying and then making the substitution for I yields \eqref{eq:bf3}.

Note that equation \eqref{eq:bf3} for the beta function appears as Equation 3 on page 9 (pdf page 35) of [Higher Transcendental Functions](http://resolver.caltech.edu/CaltechAUTHORS:20140123-104529738) (Bateman Manuscript), Volume 1.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding Nemo's answer,
setting
$x = \frac1{y}$,
so
$dy = -\frac{dy}{y^2}$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{m+n}}dx
&=-\int_{\infty}^{1}\frac{1}{y^{n-1}(1+1/y)^{m+n}}\frac{dy}{y^2}\\
&=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{y^{m+n}dy}{y^{n+1}(y+1)^{m+n}}\\
&=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{y^{m-1}dy}{(y+1)^{m+n}}\\
\end{array}
$

and his result is verified.

Note:
Here is Nem's answer which,
for some reason,
was deleted:

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{m-1}+x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{m+n}}dx&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{m-1}}{(1+x)^{m+n}}dx+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n-1}}{(1+x)^{m+n}}dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{m-1}}{(1+x)^{m+n}}dx+\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{m-1}}{(1+x)^{m+n}}dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{m-1}}{(1+x)^{m+n}}dx\\
&=B(m,n)
\end{align}

Comment: I do not see Nemo's answer. Do you have a link?

Comment: @poweierstrass: It was deleted, so I copied it and added it to my answer.